# Using ResizeObserver in React class component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, resize

I am using React 15 on Chrome and want to hook up an event listener to detect changes to a parent container. After looking around for options, I came across ResizeObserver and am not sure how to get it to work in my project.

Currently, I am putting it in my constructor but it does not seem to print any text and I am not sure what to put in the `observe` call.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
            console.log("Hello World");
        });

        resizeObserver.observe(somethingGoesHere);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <AnotherComponent>
                <YetAnotherComponent>
                </YetAnotherComponent>

                <CanYouBelieveIt>
                </CanYouBelieveIt>

                <RealComponent />
            </AnotherComponent>
        );
    }
}
```

Ideally, I also don't want to wrap `RealComponent` in a `div` and give that `div` an id. Is there a way to the `RealComponent` directly?

My goal is to observe any resize changes to the `RealComponent` but `MyComponent` is fine too. What should I put in the `somethingGoesHere` slot?

EDIT:

For the sake of getting something to work, I bit the bullet and wrapped a `div` tag around `RealComponent`. I then gave it an id `<div id="myDivTag">` and changed the `observe` call:

```
resizeObserver.observe(document.getElementById("myDivTag"));
```

However, when running this, I get:

> Uncaught TypeError: resizeObserver.observe is not a function

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

EDIT: Davidicus's answer below is more complete, look there first

ResizeObserver can't go in the constructor because the div doesn't exist at that point in the component lifecycle.

I don't think you can get around the extra div because react components reduce to html elements anyway.

Put this in componentDidMount and it should work:

```
componentDidMount() {
   const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
        console.log("Hello World");
   });

   resizeObserver.observe(document.getElementById("myDivTag"));
}
```

Comment: Is it good react practice to create instances inside a component like that?

Answer (score 19):

`ComponentDidMount` would be the best place to set up your observer but you also want to disconnect on `ComponentWillUnmount`.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  resizeObserver = null;
  resizeElement = createRef();

  componentDidMount() {
    this.resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
      // do things
    });

    this.resizeObserver.observe(this.resizeElement.current);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.resizeObserver) {
      this.resizeObserver.disconnect();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={this.resizeElement}>
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I was fighting a the similar problem recently with the difference that my app is predominantly using hooks and functional components.

Here is an example how to use the ResizeObserver within a React functional component (in typescript):

```
const resizeObserver = React.useRef<ResizeObserver>(new ResizeObserver((entries:ResizeObserverEntry[]) => {
    // your code to handle the size change
}));

const resizedContainerRef = React.useCallback((container: HTMLDivElement) => {
    if (container !== null) {
        resizeObserver.current.observe(container);
    }
    // When element is unmounted, ref callback is called with a null argument
    // => best time to cleanup the observer
    else {
        if (resizeObserver.current)
            resizeObserver.current.disconnect();
    }
}, [resizeObserver.current]);

return <div ref={resizedContainerRef}>
    // Your component content here
</div>;
```

Comment: What TS target are you using? I am getting an error with target:es6.

Comment: @Christophe I think 2015. ResizeObserver is not supported in any version of IE, you might need to use some polyfill like https://github.com/que-etc/resize-observer-polyfill. I luckily don't have to worry about ie. support anymore.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { useLayoutEffect } from 'react';

import { debounce } from '@/common/utils';

export interface UseResizeObserverConfig {
  lazy?: boolean;
  debounceTimeout?: number;
}

export const useResizeObserver = <T extends HTMLElement>(ref: React.MutableRefObject<T>, cb: (node: T) => void, config: UseResizeObserverConfig) => {

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if(!ref.current) {
      return;
    }
    cb(ref.current);
    if(config.lazy) {
      return;
    }
    const debouncedSetSize = debounce(cb, config.debounceTimeout || 200);

    const handleSaveNodeSize = (node?: T | null) => {
      if(!node) {
        return;
      }
      debouncedSetSize(node);
    };

    const onResize = (entries: ResizeObserverEntry[]) => {
      const [entry] = entries;
      handleSaveNodeSize(entry?.target as T);
    };


    const resizeObserverRef = new ResizeObserver(onResize);


    resizeObserverRef.observe(ref.current);


    return () => {
      resizeObserverRef.disconnect();
      debouncedSetSize.cancel();
    };
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  }, [ref.current, config.debounceTimeout, config.lazy]);

};
```